# Introducing 2 Cats Of Same Age (keeps fighting)

Tags: cats, behavior

So me and my friend has 7 month old male and female cat, respectively. We tried to introduce them but they always end up fighting with each other. They both belong to same mother but were separated at young age. How much time will they take and what is the best way to introduce them.

Comment: Are they neutered/castrated because you shouldn't be introducing males and females otherwise (even if they are brother and sister).

We had this situation where we brought the female cat into the house because she could no longer live with her mum (cat) and so she was re-introduced to her brother - they never truly got on, but after a few weeks they general stopped fighting etc. You need to provide more detail on how you're trying to introduce them, when they are fighting (is it meal times, some other time?)

Comment: Neutering the male will almost always make him less aggressive, but spaying a female can make her ***more*** agressive (according to a veterinarian journal I read 2007)

Comment: The method I know is shut the new one in a room with everything it needs and let the other have the rest of the house. After a week let them into the others spaces without the other cat present. For the next three days wedge the door open enough for them to get a paw or nose out but not enough to get through and play with them both with a piece of string. Then let them have full contact with each other. Play and pat with them both as much as you can the whole time.